# Get the floor value under modular division for very large number.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have got 3 numbers a,b and m(m is prime). a is very very large(around 10^10^5). I have to calculate (floor(a/b))%m. Since a is very large, so I have stored 'a' as string then calculated value of a under mod m using code below:

```
long long int len = a.length();
long long int ans=0;
for(long long int i = 0; i<len;i++){
    ans=(ans*10 + (a[i]-'0'))%m;
}
return ans;
```

Then I simply multiplied above value with the multiplicative mod inverse of b(I have calculated multiplicative mod inverse of b using fermat's little theorem.)

But this is not the desired answer. This will give me exact value of (a/b)%m. But I have to calculate (floor(a/b))%m.

Example: a=7, b=2 and m=5. Since a can be very very large(10^10^5), I just cant store 'a' directly. I must store it under mod m. So now a becomes 2(7%5 = 2).

Now I perform (a/b)%m=(2/2)%5 = 1.
But my actual answer should have(floor(7/2)%5)=3%5=3.

I am stuck here. Can anyone help me to get the desired answer.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening in your for-loop?

Comment: $b^{-1}(10a_1 + a_0) \mod m = 10a_1b^{-1} + a_1b^{-1} \mod m  = (10a_1b\mod m) + (a_1b \mod m)$.  So why not just multiply by the mod inverse as you go along?

Comment: How can it "give me exact value of `(a/b)%m`" when `b` does not appear in the code?

Comment: I don't think the question has anything to do with the multiplicative inverse of $b\pmod m$.  With $m=29,b=13,a=17$, it is clear that $\lfloor \frac ab\rfloor =1$.  But the multiplicative inverse of $13\pmod {29}$ is $9$, so you'd get $17\times 9 \equiv 8 \pmod {29}$.  No connection.

Comment: @WeatherVane It means suppose a=7, b=3 and m=5. then floor of a/b=2 and 2%5=2.  But I am getting answer for (a/b)%m.

Comment: Please add that information *to the question*. But as I say, the code you post does not use `b`. The string `a[]` is an ASCII or other character string and not an array of digits, that should be mentioned too.

Comment: @lulu I cant directly do a/b. Because a is very large I can store it, only under mod m. Since I have already calculated a%m. So when I do floor((a%m)/b)%m, it is giving me wrong answer.

Comment: If `b` fits an integer type you can do a "longhand" division, holding a carry typically larger than 1.

Comment: You get a different answer because your computation is unrelated to the given problem.

Comment: @lulu Can you tell me how do I i can calculate (floor(a/b))%m?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am editing question with 1 example.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have updated question with the example.

Comment: @lulu My main problem is a. If can fit in the integer or long range then I can directly do (a/b)%m. But I must store a as a%m. I don't have any other option. So when I already mod the value of numerator then I have to multiply it with multiplicative mod inverse of denominator.

Comment: You don't mention the size of $b$ or $m$. If they will fit an integer type, and all values are positive, I can only suggest first computing $a' = a / b$ and discard the remainder (leaving the floor), and then finding the remainder of $a' / m$. Incidentally, it is better to work with digit values and not with characters, which spares you having to convert to and fro. It is possible to do both divisions in a single loop, not two, but it is easier to write a simple division function and use it twice.

Comment: @WeatherVane b and m are integer range and can fit in memory. But I cant store 'a' directly. So for a'=a/b. First I needed the exact value of a. Which can't be store in any data type in C++(Even out of the range of unsigned double).

Comment: I think everybody understands that. Just do "longhand" divisions as you would do on paper, but you'll need to carry an unusually large remainder through the iterations. It's doable.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ohh I got your point now, when you said "as you would do on paper". Thank u , thank u so much.

Comment: @DevendraVerma Is this related to [this problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/competitive/july-circuits-18/algorithm/bonus-money-867b22a1/)?

Comment: @RahulGoswami Yes, it is.

Comment: @DevendraVerma Python can handle that number.

Answer (score 2):

I would store the numbers as arrays of $1$s and $0$s in binary.  If $a$ is of order $10^{10^5}$ that is only about $300,000$ words of memory.  You need to write a function that divides two numbers of this type.  The neat thing is that if $b$ is $n$ bits long, you just need to see if $b$ is greater than or less than the first $n$ bits of $a$.  If it is, write down a $1$ in the answer and subtract $b$ from $a$.  If not, it will be less than the first $n+1$ bits of $a$, so write a $01$ and subtract $b$ again.  Once you have subtracted $b$, write as many $0$s as needed to get back to $n$ bits of what is left of $a$.  We are implementing binary long division.  When $b$ is greater than the rest of $a$ quit and you have $\lfloor \frac ab \rfloor=c$.  Now you take $c$ and divide it by $m$ the same way, but you keep the remainder instead of the quotient.

Of course, you can handle much larger numbers if you store as ints instead of bits, but the programming will be harder.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Such a brilliant idea to store 'a' as binary. Salute to you. I think this might should work. I will try this and let you know if this works.

Comment: There's no need to reinvent the wheel when it comes to bignum math. Anyways I think storing as bool instead of int is faster since I/O may be the bottleneck here (also depends on CPU arch)

Comment: @qwr:  Yes, I would just use a canned package, but I didn't think that was the spirit of the question.  I have reinvented the wheel in Excel when I wanted numbers twice as long as it provides and didn't want to give up the other features it provides.

Comment: Actually I was in programming contest and I cant use any third party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manually use binary arrays. Use [GMP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/) and it will handle everything for you. This comes out to roughly 300,000 bits or 41 kB which a computer can handle easily. Even Python and Mathematica can handle these quantities. Ex.

```
>>> 10**(10**5) // 7**12345
```